# How to make php automatically scan and add a file, ordered by date, to a download page

Tags: php, mysql, web

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this problem, I'm not brilliant at all this stuff but I know enough to get me by.

Anyway what I'm hoping for is something that will scan multiple specified url/directory (such as http://test.com/directory) for the latest uploaded files (by date/time) and add them to a global download page. in a basic format of "Filename / size / download"

Comment: Might be useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508732/file-crawler-php

Answer (score 0):

you might want to check out the php [filemtime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) function:

```
$filename = 'somefile.txt';
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "$filename was last modified: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($filename));
}
```